# Cluster only runs with 7 or fewer tasks using MPI

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, cluster-computing, slurm

I finally got my program working on the cluster using MPI, but once I scaled it past 7 tasks I get a segmentation fault. I went back to a super basic program, below, and I still get the segmentation fault past 7 cores. To debug, I allocated 8 cores to myself on the cluster to directly work on rather than submitting a slurm job. I get the issue using Intel compiler and GCC. I thought it would break at 8 processors, but it is 7 and I find that a bit weird. But then again, I find the whole thing weird. Any idea of why the code breaks beyond a certain number of allocated cores (on the same node might I add).

On the cluster I use this:
$salloc -n 8

$enable_lmod

$module load icc/19 impi/19 libstdcxx/4

$mpiicpc -std=c++11 -o MPItest test.cpp

$mpiexec.hydra ./MPItest test

---

```
#include "mpi.h"

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
int numtasks, rank, dest, source, rc, count, tag=1;  
double inmsg, outmsg=20.0;
MPI_Status Stat;

MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

if (rank == 0) 
{
  printf("Number of processors: %d \n",numtasks);
  for (int i=1; i<numtasks;i++)
  {
    dest = i;
    outmsg+=outmsg;
    rc = MPI_Send(&outmsg, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }

  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  for (int i=1; i<numtasks;i++)
  {
    source = i;
    rc = MPI_Recv(&inmsg, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Stat);

    rc = MPI_Get_count(&Stat, MPI_DOUBLE, &count);
    printf("Task %d: Received %d double(s), %f, from task %d with tag %d \n",
       rank, count,inmsg, Stat.MPI_SOURCE, Stat.MPI_TAG);
  }  
} 

else
{
  dest = 0;
  source = 0;
  rc = MPI_Recv(&inmsg, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Stat);

  rc = MPI_Get_count(&Stat, MPI_DOUBLE, &count);
  printf("Task %d: Received %d double(s), %f, from task %d with tag %d \n",
        rank, count,inmsg, Stat.MPI_SOURCE, Stat.MPI_TAG);

  rc = MPI_Send(&inmsg, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Stat` is used uninitialized on `rank > 1`, and you should also `return 0;` at the end of the main subroutine.

Comment: You're right. I fixed that and changed it a bit to work towards what I will need. It still throws a seg fault. But, now it seg faults at 8 tasks rather than 7.

Comment: By the way, it makes more sense to have `MPI_Barrier` before `MPI_Send` in worker code.

Comment: Any stack trace or other debugging efforts to share ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet No need to `return 0;` since C++11, it's implicit: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#5.sentence-2.

Comment: Have you tried to move the barrier in slaves (non-root processes) between `MPI_Recv` and `MPI_Send`? It can cause at least deadlock as written now.

Comment: I changed to GCC in order to run a stack trace, since the cluster either doesn't have IDB/GDB or I can't figure out how it is called on their system, and the program compiles and runs perfectly with g++. It seems to be an intel compiler issue. I might try it with clang to see if I can replicate it or narrow it down to the intel compiler.

Comment: Your program is incorrect according to the MPI Standard. See here: https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report/node140.htm#Node140. If `MPI_Send` in a slave will block (which may), then you will have a deadlock.

Comment: Just ran a batch job of the above code compiled using g++ with 100 cores and the output file is correct. So, it certainly seems to be either Intel compiler related or how I am using it. I saw significant performance increases with the intel compiler and I was using the AVX2 flag for specific nodes. But, it isn't so fast if it is broken.

I will take a look at the deadlock issues you mentioned. Though I added that long after the seg fault issue. But it is still worth fixing.

Comment: My original code (the scientific code I was going to scrap, not the original test code), also works fine using GCC and OpenMPI. I was also experiencing an issue when I would run some test using the AVX2 flag where every job submitted with the AVX2 flag at compilation failed. So, perhaps there is an issue with how I compile with the Intel compiler or, wayyyyyy less likely, there's an Intel compiler install issue. But I compiled the way they recommended. Do any of you have an idea of what could cause failure with a certain compiler like this? Intel picking up bad programming GCC isn't?

Comment: Are you sure this is a `SIGSEGV` and not a `SIGILL` ?

Comment: Very well could be. When I try to run GDB or IDB it days it doesn't exist. So, I'm not able to debug it and I can't replicate it on my own system yet as I can't get OpenMPI working yet. But j only have 8 physical cores so I'm not sure if it'll reproduce it anyway.